# Removing a part of URL from coulmn in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a URL column in the table and below are the URL's. I want to remove the string after Location.

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/46/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location3
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location2/4_.000
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/52/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location5
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location6/8_.000
```

Expected OutPut

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/46/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location3
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location2
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/52/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location5
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location6
```

Tried with `charindex` but couldn't get succeeded. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on your sample data, `Left(url, 74)` would suffice. However I suspect it's more subtle than that. Can you adjust your sample data to illustrate?

Answer (score 0):

You detect the index of "/" after Location, something like this

```
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(200) = 'https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location2/4_.000'

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN charindex('/', @data, charindex('Location', @data)) = 0
        THEN @data
    ELSE LEFT(@data, charindex('/', @data, charindex('Location', @data)) - 1)
    END
```

Comment: That wouldn't word with a URL that contains 'Location' in the middle:
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Location/PlaceDetails/Location2/4_.000

Comment: You are right, in that case you can reverse it to lokk for the last 'Location'

Comment: Thank Yo so Much :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using the following algorithm:

1. Tokenize URL as XML.
2. Get position of the XML element the contains "Location".
3. Retrieve XML elements up to the position from the step above, and reassemble URL back.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [URL] VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([URL]) VALUES
('https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/46/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location3'),
('https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location2/4_.000'),
('https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/52/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location5'),
('https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location6/8_.000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/'

SELECT t.* 
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() le sql:column("t2.pos")]/text())')
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,SPACE(1),@separator) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE([URL], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('for $i in /root/r[contains(.,"Location")]
      let $pos := count(root/*[. << $i]) + 1
      return $pos').value('.','INT')) AS t2(pos)        ;
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                                   Result                                   |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/46/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location3 |
|  2 | https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location2 |
|  3 | https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/52/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location5 |
|  4 | https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/tender/lp/50/Lists/PlaceDetails/Location6 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```